# NameError: name 'SQLAlchemy' is not defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've installed SQLAlchemy by adding it through project settings but am getting this error which i can't seem to figure out:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/backup/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/app.py", line 5, in 
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
NameError: name 'SQLAlchemy' is not defined

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
        completed=db.Column(db.integer, default=0)
        date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Where did you import it?

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to import sqlalchemy module in the beginning:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Comment: from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy this doesn't work so i imported through the settings into the venv my project is in. It comes up with this error if i import it like you've suggested: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/backup/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

Comment: have you installed `flask_sqlalchemy` package? `pip install flask_sqlalchemy`. `sqlalchemy` is a different package.